# Why My java script calculator is not working

Tags: javascript

I want to make a calculator that shows the numbers clicked before calculating. this version is not completed but the code that shows the numbers is completed but its not working as supposed.

```js
function getHistory() {
  return document.querySelector(".history-value").innerText;
}

function printHistory(num) {
  document.querySelector(".history-value").innerText = num;
}

function getOutput() {
  document.getElementById("output-value").innertxt;
}

function printOutput(num) {
  document.getElementById("output-value").innerText = num;
}
let getOperator = document.getElementsByClassName("operator");
for (var i = 0; i < getOperator.length; i++) {
  getOperator[i].addEventListener("click", function() {
    //uncompleted code
  })
}

let getNumber = document.getElementsByClassName("number");
for (var i = 0; i < getNumber.length; i++) {
  getNumber[i].addEventListener("click", function() {
    let output = getOutput();
    if (output != NaN) {
      output = output + this.id
      printOutput(output)
    }
  })
}
```

```html
<div class="container">
  <div class="calculator">
    <div class="result">
      <div class="history">
        <p class="history-value"></p>
      </div>
      <div class="output">
        <p id="output-value"></p>
      </div>
    </div>
    <div class="keyboard">
      <button class="operator" id="clear">C</button>
      <button class="operator" id="backspace">CE</button>
      <button class="operator" id="%">%</button>
      <button class="operator" id="/">&#247;</button>
      <button class="number" id="7">7</button>
      <button class="number" id="8">8</button>
      <button class="number" id="9">9</button>
      <button class="operator" id="*">&times;</button>
      <button class="number" id="4">4</button>
      <button class="number" id="5">5</button>
      <button class="number" id="6">6</button>
      <button class="operator" id="-">-</button>
      <button class="number" id="1">1</button>
      <button class="number" id="2">2</button>
      <button class="number" id="3">3</button>
      <button class="operator" id="+">+</button>
      <button class="empty" id="empty"></button>
      <button class="number" id="0">0</button>
      <button class="empty" id="empty"></button>
      <button class="operator" id="=">=</button>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

It has to show in the output all the numbers I've pressed but it is showing undefined plus the last pressed number

Comment: [How do I create a runnable stack snippet?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/358992)

Comment: Hi! Please post your actual question inside of your post. I presumed you were having issues with it showing `undefined` before the number, however, If that's not what you're looking for there's no way for me to know. Post your question in the question :)

Comment: @radarbob no it doesn't work :(

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The culprit is in this function here:

```
function getOutput(){
  document.getElementById("output-value").innertxt;
}
```

Two issues here:

1- Mind the typo: it's `innerText`, not `innertxt`!
2- This function is not returning the value is the innerText, in fact it returns nothing to the code that called it, hence the "undefined".

Also to show all numbers pressed, you can append the number to the string `output` using `+=`, like this:

```
if (output!=NaN) {
      output+=this.id
      printOutput(output)
    }
```

(Also add a similar thing to the operators' `onclick` handler).

```html
<body>
    <div class="container">
      <div class="calculator">
        <div class="result">
          <div class="history">
            <p class="history-value"></p>
          </div>
          <div class="output">
            <p id="output-value"></p>
          </div>
        </div>
        <div class="keyboard">
          <button class="operator" id="clear">C</button>
          <button class="operator" id="backspace">CE</button>
          <button class="operator" id="%">%</button>
          <button class="operator" id="/">&#247;</button>
          <button class="number" id="7">7</button>
          <button class="number" id="8">8</button>
          <button class="number" id="9">9</button>
          <button class="operator" id="*">&times;</button>
          <button class="number" id="4">4</button>
          <button class="number" id="5">5</button>
          <button class="number" id="6">6</button>
          <button class="operator" id="-">-</button>
          <button class="number" id="1">1</button>
          <button class="number" id="2">2</button>
          <button class="number" id="3">3</button>
          <button class="operator" id="+">+</button>
          <button class="empty" id="empty"></button>
          <button class="number" id="0">0</button>
          <button class="empty" id="empty"></button>
          <button class="operator" id="=">=</button>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
    <script>
    function getHistory(){
       return document.querySelector(".history-value").innerText;
     }
    function printHistory(num){
      document.querySelector(".history-value").innerText=num;
    }
    function getOutput(){
      return document.getElementById("output-value").innerText;
    }
    function printOutput(num){
      document.getElementById("output-value").innerText=num;
    }
    let getOperator= document.getElementsByClassName("operator");
    for (var i = 0; i < getOperator.length; i++) {
      getOperator[i].addEventListener("click",function(){
    //uncompleted code
      })
    }
    let getNumber= document.getElementsByClassName("number");
    for (var i = 0; i < getNumber.length; i++) {
      getNumber[i].addEventListener("click",function(){
        let output=getOutput();
        if (output!=NaN) {
          output+=this.id
          printOutput(output)
        }
      })
    }
    </script>
  </body>
</html>
```

Comment: Glad this helps! If this worked, consider marking this post as the answer.

Answer (score 0):

It's because `output` doesn't get any value from the function `getOutput` since nothing's being returned.

Because of that fact `output` is set to `undefined`. When you concatenate undefined with `id` (the number), whatever it may be, they are coerced to strings. This means you get "undefined7", "undefined9", "undefined*n*", etc.

```
      let output=getOutput(); // output is undefined.
      if (output!=NaN) {
      output=output+this.id //output plus n is "undefinedn"
```

To prove this we can use short-circuit evaluation:

```
      let output=getOutput(); // output is undefined.
      if (output!=NaN) {
      output= output || "" + this.id //output plus n is "n"
```

This checks if `output` is `falsy` - since `undefined` **is** `falsy`, it returns an empty string and concats that with `this.id` instead.

---

Example:

```html
<body>
    <div class="container">
      <div class="calculator">
        <div class="result">
          <div class="history">
            <p class="history-value"></p>
          </div>
          <div class="output">
            <p id="output-value"></p>
          </div>
        </div>
        <div class="keyboard">
          <button class="operator" id="clear">C</button>
          <button class="operator" id="backspace">CE</button>
          <button class="operator" id="%">%</button>
          <button class="operator" id="/">&#247;</button>
          <button class="number" id="7">7</button>
          <button class="number" id="8">8</button>
          <button class="number" id="9">9</button>
          <button class="operator" id="*">&times;</button>
          <button class="number" id="4">4</button>
          <button class="number" id="5">5</button>
          <button class="number" id="6">6</button>
          <button class="operator" id="-">-</button>
          <button class="number" id="1">1</button>
          <button class="number" id="2">2</button>
          <button class="number" id="3">3</button>
          <button class="operator" id="+">+</button>
          <button class="empty" id="empty"></button>
          <button class="number" id="0">0</button>
          <button class="empty" id="empty"></button>
          <button class="operator" id="=">=</button>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
    <script>
    function getHistory(){
       return document.querySelector(".history-value").innerText;
     }
    function printHistory(num){
      document.querySelector(".history-value").innerText=num;
    }
    function getOutput(){
      document.getElementById("output-value").innertxt;
    }
    function printOutput(num){
      document.getElementById("output-value").innerText=num;
    }
    let getOperator= document.getElementsByClassName("operator");
    for (var i = 0; i < getOperator.length; i++) {
      getOperator[i].addEventListener("click",function(){
    //uncompleted code
      })
    }
    let getNumber= document.getElementsByClassName("number");
    for (var i = 0; i < getNumber.length; i++) {
      getNumber[i].addEventListener("click",function(){
        let output=getOutput();
        if (output!=NaN) {
          output=output||""+this.id
          printOutput(output)
        }
      })
    }
    </script>
  </body>
</html>
```

Comment: but how can I solve it to show all the numbers pressed